# How to correctly unload (deallocate/dispose) glTF or OBJ model in Aframe?

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality, aframe, webvr, gltf

I'm trying to create a multi-room environment using aframe. In each room, there will a be a few objects to interact with, and these models are loaded from glTF or OBJ files.

On mobile phones, we have a very limited amount of ram, so I've wanted to clear unused models when user teleports/moves to another room. But I don't know how to achieve that.
I've found some related issues that suggest to use `document.querySelector('a-scene').systems.material.textureCache`, but I've not found my model there (because it's a model, not a texture). I've tried to use `THREE.Cache` method, but with it, I can only some cached data, not at all.

I'm using model(creating an entity) like this:

`<a-gltf-model id="m4_obj" src="/models/m4a1/scene.gltf" position="0.713 1 -5.156" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"  ></a-gltf-model>`

So, there my attempts to clear a cache:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfsbD.png

Snapshot 22 was taken after the load.

Snapshot 23 was taken after executing `document.getElementById("m4_obj").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("m4_obj"));`

Snapshot 24 was taken after executing this:

```
for (let elem in THREE.Cache.files){
    if (elem.startsWith('/models/m4a1/')){
        THREE.Cache.remove(elem)
    }
}
```

`/models/m4a1/` - is a folder with a model that I want to delete.
But if I comment this object, my snapshot become as 56mb! https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpe7e.png

So, how I should properly remove a model from the scene, to dispose it fully? Thanks!

Comment: If you've removed the HTML element from the scene and also removed items from THREE.Cache, but the data still seems to be in memory, could you file an issue on the A-Frame Github? This sounds like a bug, and may be hard to solve here.

Comment: You may also need to call `dispose()` on any textures the model uses.